# How to estimate preferred UIView size where one of the child views uses ratio constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, measure

I've realised that I don't understand AutoLayout.

I want to measure view's required height given the constant width.

This is my TestViewTwo.xib

[image: TestViewTwo.xib]

TestViewTwo.swift

```
import UIKit

class TestViewTwo: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        let nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TestViewTwo", owner: self, options: nil)
        let view = nib!.first as! UIView
        addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Test Controller

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TestControllerTwo : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let testView = TestViewTwo()
        
        let estimatedSize = testView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: 200, height: 500))
        
        print("Estimated size: \(estimatedSize), imageView.frame: \(testView.imageView.frame)")
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Estimated size: (100.0, 500.0), imageView.frame: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 621.0)
```

I don't understand why estimated width is 100 ? Where is this coming from ?
Why estimated height is 500 and not 300 (200x1.5) ?
I also don't understand why imageView frame is set and why to such values

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

**I want to get estimatedSize = 200x300**

### Update:

I guess there is something fundamentally wrong I'm doing here.
It is not about ratio that I use.

When I set constant width and height of image view

[image]

I get

```
Estimated size: (200.0, 500.0), imageView.frame: (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 300.0)
```

When I set constant height only

[image]

I get

```
Estimated size: (100.0, 500.0), imageView.frame: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 300.0)
```

**What is wrong in my layout / code so that I don't get estimatedSize = 200x300 ?**

Let's deal with constant dimensions before moving to ratio problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to constrain the bottom of the image view to the bottom of its superview...

[image]

Give the bottom constraint `Priority: High (750)`

Then, when you want to know the estimated ***Height*** based on a given rectangle:

```
    let estimatedSize = testView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: 200, height: 500),
                                     withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh,
                                     verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow)

    print("Estimated size: \(estimatedSize), imageView.frame: \(testView.imageView.frame)")
    
    // output: Estimated size: (200.0, 300.0), imageView.frame: (0.0, 0.0, 197.0, 295.5)
```

If you want to know the estimated ***Width*** based a given rectangle:

```
    let estimatedSize = testView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: 200, height: 500),
                                     withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultLow,
                                     verticalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh)
    
    print("Estimated size: \(estimatedSize), imageView.frame: \(testView.imageView.frame)")

    // output: Estimated size: (333.5, 500.0), imageView.frame: (0.0, 0.0, 197.0, 295.5)
```

Note that the `imageView.frame` will ***NOT*** be set yet, so it will evaluate to whatever size you have it in IB.

Also note that we give the image view a Bottom constraint with a **less-than-required** Priority. This avoids the IB warnings when we don't have the view frame sized to exactly `1:1.5` ratio, and avoids auto-layout warning/errors messages at run-time.

---

Here is the source to the XIB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_0" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17703"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="TestViewTwo" customModule="DrawingTutorial" customModuleProvider="target">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="imageView" destination="QgA-Qr-3jM" id="MGu-3W-9i4"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="197" height="391"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="QgA-Qr-3jM">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="197" height="295.5"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99998801950000005" green="0.62141335009999998" blue="0.00022043679199999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="QgA-Qr-3jM" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1.5" id="CpW-r1-rJA"/>
                    </constraints>
                </imageView>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45009386540000001" green="0.98132258650000004" blue="0.4743030667" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="QgA-Qr-3jM" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" id="3As-tz-AZL"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="QgA-Qr-3jM" secondAttribute="trailing" id="4Q2-dC-O75"/>
                <constraint firstItem="QgA-Qr-3jM" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" id="xJ2-05-m7l"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="QgA-Qr-3jM" secondAttribute="bottom" priority="750" id="xy9-yL-2gg"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="109.6875" y="126.23239436619718"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

And example classes to demonstrate:

```
class TestControllerTwo : UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let testView = TestViewTwo()
        
        // withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh
        // verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow
        //  gives priority to the WIDTH
        //  returns a size based on fitting the Target WIDTH
        let estimatedSizeW = testView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
            CGSize(width: 200, height: 500),
            withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh,
            verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow)
        
        print("Width Priority Estimated size: \(estimatedSizeW)",
            "imageView.frame: \(testView.imageView.frame)")

        // withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultLow
        // verticalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh
        //  gives priority to the HEIGHT
        //  returns a size based on fitting the Target HEIGHT
        let estimatedSizeH = testView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
            CGSize(width: 200, height: 500),
            withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultLow,
            verticalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh)
        
        print("Height Priority Estimated size: \(estimatedSizeH)",
            "imageView.frame: \(testView.imageView.frame)")
        
    }

}

class TestViewTwo: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        let nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TestViewTwo", owner: self, options: nil)
        let view = nib!.first as! UIView
        addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show or say what is inside collapsed constraints under image view ?

Comment: @ievgen - sorry, I usually double- and triple-check that I have everything expanded in the Document Outline. See the edits to my answer... I replaced the screen-cap, and included the XIB source as well as example code for the classes (the `TestViewTwo` class is exactly what you posted in your question).

Answer (score 1):

It's a common problem with `systemLayoutSizeFitting` that it is not working correctly when you use aspect ratio. It is using the `intrinsicContentSize` to set its height, so therefore the  different value you get. In order to solve the issue you need to remove the aspect ratio and set the height explicitly. In code it would look like:

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
```

Also [see][1] a similar answer.

#### Update:

After you provided a bit more information, I see a few issues there:

1. You are getting 500 for the height because you are trying to estimate the `TestViewTwo` height, not the actual `UIImageView`'s. `TestViewTwo` will have a 500 height as it does not have a bottom anchor and will stretch to fill the available space.
2. For the estimation a better fit would be to use `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:)`

Based on the documentation:

> Use this method when you want to prioritize the view's constraints
> when determining the best possible size of the view. This method does
> not actually change the size of the view.

Applying those changes I prepared a demo for you, so you can verify it and  play around with that. I named the View which is holding the `UIImageView` to `ImageView`:

```
class ImageView: UIView {
    let imageView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

The `TestViewTwo` I named `ImageViewHolder`:

```
class ImageViewHolder: UIView {
    let view = ImageView(frame: .zero)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        // Bottom anchor should not be set here, as the view has explicitly defined it's height
        backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

And here is the ViewController where you can test it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // I gave a frame to this so you can see the actual layout
        // But the estimation logic also works if you pass here .zero a
        let imageViewHollder = ImageViewHolder(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 200, height: 500)) 

        let estimatedSize = imageViewHollder.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: 200, height: 500), withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh)
        print("Estimated size: \(estimatedSize)")
        
        // Just to see the actual layout
        view.addSubview(imageViewHollder)
    }
}
```

Notice that when you are printing the estimated size of the imageView:

```
let estimatedSize = imageViewHollder.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: 200, height: 500), withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh)
print("Estimated size: \(estimatedSize)")
```

You get:

> ```
> // Estimated size: (200.0, 300.0)
> ```

But if you print the estimated size of the view which holds it

```
let estimatedSize = imageViewHollder.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: 200, height: 500), withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh)
print("Estimated size: \(estimatedSize)")
```

You get

> Estimated size: (200.0, 500.0)

That's because as explained above, the holder view will try to fill the available space as it has no bottom anchor.

Comment: I've tested your proposal, it didn't work. So I decided to make a step back and try to estimate the view size with constant dimensions. It doesn't work either. So I feel there is something fundamentally wrong in my layout / code and updated my question